# How can i fix this game?

Tags: c#

So basically i started to learn some c# a while ago and i am still a newbie, i wanted to make a guessing game which will have a list base of strings and after 5 failed tries will give one char from the chosen word from the list, my problem was when i tried to to limit max tries after there is no more index of chars in the word, i hope you understand, appreciate the help <3

```
internal class Program
{

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> Taha = new List<string> { "Text", "Test", "Report", "Elephant", "GingerCat", "Cute", "Beach" };
        Random r = new Random();
        int index = r.Next(Taha.Count);
        string randomString = Taha[index];
        Console.WriteLine(randomString);
        Secret(randomString);
    }
    static void Secret(string SecretWord)
    {
        string Guess = null;
        double num = 0;
        int countLetters = 0;
        int Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Guess:");
        Guess = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Guess == SecretWord)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nice One!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed Guess");
            num++;
            Console.WriteLine("First Letter Revealed, The Letter is " + SecretWord[0]);
        }
        while (Guess != SecretWord)
        {
            double NumberDivided = num / 5;
            Console.WriteLine("Divided Number is " + NumberDivided);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of tries is " + num);
            Console.WriteLine("Length Number " + SecretWord.Length);
            Length = SecretWord.Length;
            if (countLetters == Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have reached max tries unlucky");
            }
            else if (NumberDivided % 1 == 0.0 && countLetters != Length)
            {
                num++;
                countLetters++;
                Console.WriteLine("Letter Number " + countLetters);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Guess:");
                Guess = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Letter Number " + (countLetters + 1) + " Reavled, The Letter is " + SecretWord[countLetters]);
                //break;
            }
            else
            {
                num++;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Guess:");
                Guess = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Very Good");
    }
}
```

tried to code the game and expecting it to work xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be able to help. I'm about intermediate at C# and I've been building games with it as well.

It looks like this is where your problem lies:

```
else if (NumberDivided % 1 == 0.0 && countLetters != Length)
{
     num++;
     countLetters++;
     Console.WriteLine("Letter Number " + countLetters);
     Console.WriteLine("Enter Guess:");
     Guess = Console.ReadLine();
     Console.WriteLine("Letter Number " + (countLetters + 1) + " Reavled, The Letter is " + SecretWord[countLetters]);
     //break;
 }
```

Console.WriteLine("Letter Number " + (countLetters + 1) + " Reavled, The Letter is " + SecretWord[countLetters]);

In the line of code I copied and pasted above, you add 1 to countLetters and then later you use it in SecretWord[countLetters]. You have said to do that "if" the remainder is zero. It was zero, and then you added 1 to the index.

That will have incremented it outside the bounds of the array; it added 1 too many.

You need to use an if statement to catch this:

```
if (countLetters > SecretWord.Length)
{
    // Do something here that prevents your exception
}
```

You may also want to explore flipping it around and doing this:

```
if (countLetters <= SecretWord.Length)
{
     // Your game does what it is supposed to
}
else
{
    // make sure you don't get that error
}

// that if statment is one way to say "if it is not greater than"
```

I hope that helps you. Keep at it. I love your take on the C# guessing game!

Comment: Thank you very much for help <3 i managed to rewrite the code again so it will be more easier for me and the result is way much better

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @therealchriswoodward managed to understand more and i have wrote the code again here is my fix
**Also added last if incase user guess the word :D

```
internal class Program
```

{

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> Taha = new List<string> { "test", "text", "Report", "ReportFile", "GingerCat", "cute", "Beach" };
    Random r = new Random();
    int index = r.Next(Taha.Count);
    string randomString = Taha[index];
    Console.WriteLine(randomString);
    Secret(randomString);
}
static void Secret(string SecretWord)
{
    string Guess = null;
    double num = 0;
    int countLetters = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Guess:");
    Guess = Console.ReadLine();
    if (Guess == SecretWord)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nice One!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed Guess");
        num++;
        Console.WriteLine("First Letter Revealed, The Letter is " + SecretWord[0]);
        countLetters++;
    }
    while (Guess != SecretWord)
    {
        num++;
        if (num % 5 == 0)
        {
            if (countLetters < SecretWord.Length)
            {
                countLetters++;
                Console.WriteLine("Count Letter Number is " + countLetters);
                Console.WriteLine("Letter Number " + countLetters + " Reavled, The Letter is " + SecretWord[(countLetters - 1)]);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Guess:");
                Guess = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have reached max tries unlucky, cya");
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Guess:");
            Guess = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

}